# Unable to interpret a line of python code that creates a LSTM cell using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I am trying to figure out how a fully-functional python code works. One block creates a LSTM cell using tensorflow. I don't know how to interpret the line **specified by the comment** below.

```
def get_lstm_weights(n_hidden, forget_bias, dim, scope="rnn_cell"):
    # Create LSTM cell
    cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_units = n_hidden, reuse=None, forget_bias = forget_bias)
    #--------------------------------------
    # I DO NOT UNDERSTAND THE NEXT LINE
    cell(tf.zeros([1, dim +1]), (tf.zeros([1, n_hidden]),tf.zeros([1, n_hidden])), scope=scope)
    # -------------------------------------
    cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_units = n_hidden, reuse=True, forget_bias = forget_bias)

    # Create output weights
    weights = {
        'W_1': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_hidden, dim], stddev=0.05)),
        'b_1': tf.Variable(0.1*tf.ones([dim])),
    }

    return cell, weights
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that `tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell` is an example of a [callable class](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/callable-in-python/).

That is a class that can be called like a function. The line you are struggling with does exactly that. It *calls* `cell` with the parameters in brackets.

If you want to see what this does you can inspect the `__call__` method on the class definition for `tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but why repeat the same line after calling "cell"?
I mean "cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(...." line.

Does this mean two LSTM units are being created?

Comment: i can't explain the "why" I am afraid but, yes, that appears to be what's happening. `cell` is created on line 1 then called on line 2 then new `cell` is created on line 3

Comment: where did you find this code? what context is it in?

Comment: you definitely create two LSTM cells and return only one of them which might look strange, but I guess it's connected with the `scope` variable (the first `cell` is created within this `scope` unlike the second one) but still, as @Stewart_R asked, it's hard to say anything more when we do not know its context..

Comment: @Stewart_R 
The source code is available on Github. Here is the link to the whole code

https://github.com/heytitle/blackbox-optimization-using-rnns/blob/master/src/lstm_model.py